# How to load images in uitableview?

Tags: iphone

In my application i m using webservices to get the the image to load in UITableView. the images loaded in the cell and i scroll down to see other datas, if i again scroll up to see already loaded data, there the loaded images are again loading.
Why this happens. can anyone tell that how to display images in LazyTableImage example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we scroll, each time cellForRowAtInpdex is called every time.so,you should handle the image loading in someother part(say ViewDidLoad)..